# jquery convert time format

Tags: jquery, regex

i have text input to enter time and some times I need to change time from 12 hr format to 24 format when I double click on input.. so how can me convert time like this:

1:00 => 13:00

01:00 => 13:00

(hint) my code:

```
   $("input").live('dblclick', function(){
    var type12 = $(this).val();
    if (type12.length == 4){
    var time = type12.replace(/\:/, '');
    var hh = time.substr(0,1);
    var mm = time.substr(0,3); // TO DO
    var type24 = Number(hh) + 12;
    var time24 = hh + mm;
    $(this).val(time24);
    sortTimes($(this).closest("tr"));
    }else{alert('not');}
});
```

Comment: Without `am/pm`, how could you know the time is in day or night?

Comment: dosen't matter.. no problem it's for admin only

Comment: As @xdazz mentioned, you must have an am/pm meridian value, or you wouldn't be able to tell what time of day it is. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/374xN/1/  . Maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, here is what I would do. First of all you should really define a consistent string for your 12 hour time. I would use the format `hh:mm am / hh:mm pm`.

Secondly, I would ditch the `.live()` for two reason, firstly, because as of jQuery 1.7 it has been depreciated and replaced by `.on()`, and secondly because your going to need to have functionality to convert the 24 hour time back to a 12 hour time when the button is double clicked a second time. If you were using single clicks we could use a `.toggle()`, however for double clicks we will need to use a plugin, and I would recommend using the [jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin](https://github.com/fkling/jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin). Once included in your code it can be used like so:

```
$('input').funcToggle('dblclick', function() {
    //Odd Click
}, function() {
    // Even Click
});
```

Next, instead of using substrings, which while perfectly fine, we could just use `.indexOf(":")`, to check if the string has a `:` in it, and then .split(":") to split the string into an array. This is how I did it:

```
var type12 = "12:45";
if (type12.indexOf(":") != -1) {
    time_array = type12.split(":");
    hh = time_array[0];  //12
    mm = time_array[1];  //45
}
```

Full code and example can be found here --> http://jsfiddle.net/374xN/4/

This is probably overkill for what you asked, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: On my case no need to show AM/PM but good job I will use it thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer

```
   $("input").live('dblclick', function(){
    var type12 = $(this).val();
    if (type12.length == 4){
        var time = type12.replace(/\:/, '');
        var hh = time.substr(0,1);
        var mm = time.substr(1,2);
        var hh = Number(hh) + 12;
        var time24 = hh + ':' + mm;
        $(this).val(time24);
    }else if(type12.length == 5 && type12.substr(0,1) == 0) {
        var time = type12.replace(/\:/, '');
        var hh = time.substr(0,2);
        var mm = time.substr(2,2);
        var hh = Number(hh) + 12;
        var time24 = hh + ':' + mm;
        $(this).val(time24);
    }
});
```